# Cannot back up my database

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, export, dump

I am trying to backup my MySQL 8 database with the command line below but I got an error message.

How to make the backup ?

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ mysqldump -u root -p www_example_com > /var/www/www-example-com/share/www-example-com_$(date +%F).sql

-bash: /var/www/www-example-com/share/www-example-com_$(date +%F).sql: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try check permissions for all directory in "/var/www/www-example-com/share" path?
Also, you could try using `sudo` (if you can)

Comment: You don't need to check the permissions for all directories in that path. The user would need read permissions for each directory in the path `/var/www/www-example-com/` and then read/write permissions for `share/`.

Comment: @Anaoliy Tk Thanks, sudo displays the same message. By changing the owner of the folder it works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the user executing mysqldump or the user you are logged in as, does not have permissions to write the backup to the directory.

I would also change the command being used to:

```
mysqldump -u root -p www_example_com > /var/www/www-example-com/share/www-example-com_"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`".sql
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795678/append-date-to-filename-in-linux